# Assigning multiple roles to a single user

Tags: asp.net, database-design, relational-database, normalization, database-normalization

I am currently designing a database with a role driven menu which has following requirements.

```
 1. Menu items can be assigned to a certain 'role'
 2. A role will be assigned to a user
 3. A user can have multiple roles
```

I have designed the database however I cannot map multiple roles to a single user in my current design. Also, I don't understand how would I map the duplicate menu items (When a user is assigned multiple roles) while querying even if I include it in my design somehow.

I though about storing roles as comma separated values however that would further introduce complications. 
Is their a better solution?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C. Trimble is right (+1).  If your menu items are available to multiple roles and your users can have multiple roles, then you actually have **two many-to-many** relationships that need to be recorded.

That means that you need to add one more table, as below:

[image: ERD]

This table could have columns as per C. Trimble's answer, or you could have a compound primary key of just UserId + RoleId - analogous to your `MenuItemRoles` table.  The latter would be my design preference since the table is a pure intersection and there is no particular reason to expect that `UserRoles` would have children relating to it.

Note that when you are retrieving user menu item access you can short-circuit the link from `UserRoles` to `MenuItemRoles` because they both have a `RoleId` column.  This means you can join directly between the intersection tables, leaving `Roles` out of it.  In TSQL it would look like:

```
select I.*   -- Never select * in the real world.
from MenuItem I
  inner join MenuItemRoles IR
  on I.ItemId = IR.ItemId
  inner join UserRoles UR
  on IR.RoleId = UR.RoleId
where
  UR.UserId = @TheUserImLookingFor
```

You could do the same thing in LINQ.  If you're using EF then you're just going to have to go the long way around (through `Roles`).

Answer (score 2):

The relationship between users and roles is a many-to-many relationship, so you are going to have to model the relationship in a table with two foreign keys.  Something like:

```
UserToRole
====================
UserToRoleId INTEGER
UserId(FK)   INTEGER
RoleId(FK)   INTEGER
```

You can then use this table to join the Users and Roles tables together and get multiple values.

Comment: Can you provide me a little more detail ? Would that require a new table?